# How to make a function that returns an rvalue reference to primary data type?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

Here's a short snippet.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int&& add(int& a, int& b) {
    return move(a + b);
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    cout << "r: " << add(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

At first, I expected that this code would work, as the `std::move()` function is converting a sum of lvalue references to the rvalue. Instead of printing out the expected line, it ends up showing a segmentation fault error.

Can somebody help me to make this work?

Comment: youre returning a reference to a temporary object that will be destroyed when the function ends. this is, as far as i know, undefined behavior. in fact when i compile your code with g++ i get *exactly* this warning: `warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]`

Comment: Re: “make this work” — what do you want it to do?

Comment: @PeteBecker to make the snippet print `r: 3`

Comment: For RVO, you can just return `a+b` as `int`.

Comment: returning a pointer or reference to a non-static function local object, which is what `move(a + b)` is, will never work.  It goes out of scope when the function ends.

Comment: *"as the `std::move()` function is converting a sum of lvalue references to the rvalue"* -- more precisely, doesn't this `std::move()` convert the rvalue that is the sum to an xvalue? I.e. nothing useful?